# How to shift x-axis label to right in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to draw a box plot using matlab. I want to shift the position of the x-axis labels to the right. See the following code which seems not to work correctly.

```
positions = [2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5];

colors = [0 0 1; 0 0 1;0 0 1; 1 0 0;1 0 0;1 0 0]; 
x = boxplot([KA_query_length Plan_query_length Comp_query_length FR_query_length KI_query_length QA_query_length], 'Position', positions, 'Colors',colors,'whisker',0);
set(gca, 'FontSize', 20,'FontWeight','bold');
```

Given below is what the graph looks like at the moment. 
[image: Matlab bar graph]

Comment: Can you add the code for generating the labels?

Comment: I would just adjust the position of XLabel of the graph